# Past text in rich text box Visual C++ without formating

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text, pasting

I'm working on my project, i'm making notepad for my self. At the moment i'm in final state(fixing bugs and adding some final things).Problem that i'm facing now is: when i paste formated text it stays formated, i want it unformated, default font, default size.I'm working in Microsoft Visual 2010 C++.
Code that i'm using for paste:

```
private: System::Void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         richTextBox1->Paste();
     }
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the code you're using for the paste

Comment: I have added paste code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Paste` method has [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23kah9ca(v=vs.110).aspx), that takes a parameter specifying the format of the data pasted. Specify [the format you want](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats_fields(v=vs.110).aspx), such as `DataFormats::Text` or `DataFormats::UnicodeText`. For example:

```
  // Get the format for the object type.
  DataFormats::Format^ myFormat = DataFormats::GetFormat( DataFormats::Text );

  // After verifying that the data can be pasted, paste it. 
  if ( richTextBox1->CanPaste( myFormat ) )
  {
     richTextBox1->Paste( myFormat );
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
     MessageBox::Show( "The data format that you attempted to paste is not supported by this control." );
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: I used both codes, but i got same errors for both of them.Even with -> i got error

With . instead of -> i got: 
'.' is illegal after UDT 'System::Windows::Forms::DataFormats'
With -> instead of . :
'System::Windows::Forms::DataFormats' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was thinking half in C#! I've edited my answer for C++. See the link for any related info you may need.